# How to fetch records who satisfy a condition of first row having value as N and then further its records having value as Y in oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table given below, I want to fetch only those records whose first record started coming as Flag - N and eventually got converted to Y (RollNo 1 and 2). But I don't need those records started flowing in table with Flag - Y and eventually converted to N (RollNo 3).

| RollNo | Name | Flag | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bob | N | Jan |
| 1 | bob | N | Feb |
| 1 | bob | Y | Mar |
| 2 | rock | N | Jan |
| 2 | rock | Y | Feb |
| 2 | rock | Y | Apr |
| 3 | john | Y | Jan |
| 3 | john | N | Feb |

Expected Output

| RollNo | Name | Flag | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bob | N | Jan |
| 1 | bob | N | Feb |
| 1 | bob | Y | Mar |
| 2 | rock | N | Jan |
| 2 | rock | Y | Feb |
| 2 | rock | Y | Apr |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `first_value()`, twice:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             first_value(flag) over (partition by rollno order by month) as first_flag,
             first_value(flag) over (partition by rollno order by month desc) as first_flag
      from t
     ) t
where first_flag = 'N' and last_flag = 'Y';
```

Note:  This assumes that "month" is really something that can be ordered, such as a date, and not an arbitrary string.

Comment: just wanted to make sure do i need to do some corrections in second partition ,give that a name last_flag?

Comment: @Salva . . . `desc` was misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LISTAGG function (its analytic version) like below

```sql
select ROLLNO, NAME, FLAG, MONTH
from (
  select ROLLNO, NAME, FLAG, MONTH, LISTAGG(FLAG)within group (order by month)over(partition by ROLLNO) flag_list
  from t
) tt
where flag_list like 'N%Y%'
;
```